# Licensing Issues while writing Community Project using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python-toolbox, license

I'm creating [a project](https://github.com/yoavabadi/ProjectInfo) for the Esri community, that uses some Basic ArcMap license, to create tools that require an Advanced (ArcInfo) license.

Is there a licensing issue to do something like this?

It's basically a Python Toolbox, that has some tools.

Comment: You need to apply for the non-profit edition (to cover licensing) https://www.esri.com/en-us/industries/sustainability/nonprofit-program/overview

Answer (score 4):

If you're writing tools/code that only require a basic license to replicate functionality available with an advanced license then go nuts, people have been doing that for years. For example, the [bounding containers](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=564e2949763943e3b9fb4240bab0ca2f) toolbox which replicates some advanced tools and only requires  a basic license is published on arcgis.com by an [Esri forums MVP and moderator](https://community.esri.com/people/Dan_Patterson).

If you're writing tools/code that require an advanced license to run, you can still develop and publish them using a basic license but you won't be able to actually test/run them but users with an advanced license will be able to.

Either way, you won't be doing anything wrong, so long as you aren't actually copying closed source/proprietary Esri code.

Comment: Thanks Luke! That's super helpul, I was a bit anxious about that, no longer :)